# Splitting Columns in R based on space

Tags: r, split, tidyr

I have a Location Column which looks like the following-

```
   Location 
   San Jose CA
   Santa Clara CA
```

I want to split into two columns. I'm using the separate function from tidyr, but giving the sep argument as " " gives me the following-

```
  City  State
  San   Jose
  Santa Clara
```

How can I split the column based on only the second space?

```
structure(list(Location = c("San Jose CA", "Santa Clara CA")),
          .Names = "Location", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @Mridul Garg Are you sure the pattern is consistent throughout the column, i.e all locations have two spaces?

Comment: No, it contains columns with just a single space as well- for example Fremont CA. These cases are the ones which are giving me trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JasonAizkalns That worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 12):

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Location = c("San Jose CA", "Fremont CA", "Santa Clara CA"))
separate(df, Location, into = c("city", "state"), sep = " (?=[^ ]+$)")

#          city state
# 1    San Jose    CA
# 2     Fremont    CA
# 3 Santa Clara    CA
```

Comment: You can use dynamic quantifiers in `tidyr` lookarounds? I really don't get the rules for when that's possible. Nice solution!

Comment: Maybe someone else can elaborate, but I believe under the covers, the `sep` argument calls `stringi::stri_split_regex`

Answer (score 1):

An option using `base R` involves replacing the last space with `,` (using `sub`) and then use `read.csv` to read the column.

```
read.csv(text=sub("\\s+(\\S+)$", ",\\1", df1$Location), 
        col.names=c('City', 'State'), header=FALSE)
#         City State
#1    San Jose    CA
#2 Santa Clara    CA
```